# why is redirect() not allowing me to finish my function call?

Tags: php, http, function, redirect, header

So i'm writing a function that will allow me to add an ID from one data base table to another to associate the two, but i've run into some trubble and can't seem to figgure out what to do. any help would be much appreaceated.

pleas excuse my some what messy code, i've been trying alot of diffrent solutions that don't seem to be working.

```
class photo_modle extends CI_Model {

var $gallery_path;
var $image_name;
var $row;
var $gid; // gallary ID
var $iid; // image ID
function photo_modle() {
ob_start();
    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images');
}

function uploadPhoto() {


    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    $this->image_name = $image_data['file_name'];
    $config = array(
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image' => realpath($this->gallery_path . '/thumb/normal/'),
        'width' => 248,
        'height' => 198,
        'maintain_ratio' => false
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    $data = array(
        'image_name' => $this->image_name,
        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name')

    );



    $str = $this->db->insert_string('images', $data);

    $this->db->query($str);
    $this->iid = $this->db->insert_id();


    $grayscale_path = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/images/thumb/normal/' . $this->image_name;
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($grayscale_path);
    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    imagejpeg($img, '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/images/thumb/rollover/' . $this->image_name, 100);
    imagedestroy($img);
    $ndata = array (
        'image_name' => $this->image_name,
        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'id' => $this->iid
         );

    $this->session->set_userdata($ndata);


}




function add_new_gallery() {


    $ndata = array(
        'gallery_name' => $this->input->post('gallery_name'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('gallery_description'),
     ); 

     $n_str = $this->db->insert('gallery', $ndata);
    // this is the only place where i can put the redirect without it returning errors
    // but if i do it here it does not pass back the gid variable which i need. 
    // I also should mention that I have a  header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); above all of
    // this, and that is why I have to do a redirect, so that I don't get an error. and that 
    // header code is nessasary, for I am doing some photo manipulation that requires it. 
     redirect('site/uploaded'); 
     $this->db->query($n_str);
     $this->gid = $this->db->insert_id();

     // I was trying to send that info in the session, but even that did not work because of the 
     // redirect
     $sdata = array(
         'gallery_id' => $this->gid
     );

     $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);


}
// this function needs the info that is not getting passed. 
function addId() {
      $sdata = array('gallery_id' => $this->session->userdata('gallery_id'));
     $where = "id = ".$this->session->userdata('image_id'); 
     $str = $this->db->update_string('images', $sdata, $where);

     $this->db->query($str);
}
```

to any one that can help thank you sooooooo much for your time. any suggestions would be great!

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: `this is the only place where i can put the redirect without it returning errors` - why? I assume this function sends headers and terminates execution, so it should be placed after all other actions.

Comment: The image “http://localhost/index.php/site/photoUploader” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: @AlexW.H.B. answer my question please, why can't you place call of "redirect" in the end of function. And show us code of your "redirect()" function.

Comment: Every time I place the redirect() at the end of ether add_new_gallery() or addId() I get the same error message which is "The image “localhost/index.php/site/photoUploader” cannot be displayed because it contains errors. " logically i know that it should be placed at the end of the function. one thing I was thinking is maybe the post data has to be read before the redirect, but im not sure what to do if that is the case.

Comment: It means you should send "Content-type" headers only if `redirect` headers will not be sent. Try to call `ob_start();` in beginning of the script.

Comment: do you mean that I should not be using a content-type header? I tried putting the ob_start(); function at the beginning of the script, and it did nothing. by the way I appreciate the help. :)

Comment: You should use this header, of course, but only not simultaneously with "Location" header. Use `@nickname` (@OZ_) when you want notice your opponent about new message. Write code of your `redirect()` function, it can help.

Comment: hey thanks for the fast reply, I understand what you are saying about not using the redirect and the header at the same time, but the rest of the message you lost me. :( sorry.

Comment: What exactly does your redirect function do? Maybe it's exiting after setting the header...

Comment: why don't i just post the rest of my code, so that you can see the extent of it. it might help to clear some things up. :)

Comment: I figured it out. :) the ob_start() was the key. thank you very much! :) you where a huge help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to send a `Content-type: image/jpeg` header if you are just *manipulating* an image, and saving results to a file.

It's **only** necessary when you are sending an image to the browser.

You may got confused on how [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) works, as it has a dual behaviour. imagejpg can:

- Output an image directly to your browser, if you dont pass it a `$filename`. Of course you need to warn the browser to expect image data, that's when you send it a content type header.
- Save the image to a file, if you do give it a `$filename`.

In your case, you do pass it a `$filename` so the image is saved to disk. But you're also sending a `Content-type: image/jpeg` so your browser is expecting to receive image data, which never happens, then it "cannot be displayed because it contains errors".

Comment: hey thank you so much for this answer! I had no idea. i just removed that content type and it works fine. i was having to redirect to another page, but now i can just have it submit to it's self. thank you for that. :)